# Angular 6 - "Unexpected directive 'NgModel'...Please add a @NgModule annotation"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, using Angular 6.

I'm trying to update the model, via a component/controller, from an input (number type).  But, importing the `NgModel` from into the main app module, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Unexpected directive 'NgModel' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

App.Module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CanvasDirective } from './canvas/canvas.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CanvasDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgModel
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<div appCanvas class="canvas"  (emitConfig)="updateCanvasConfig($event)" [param]="canvasParam"></div>

<ul *ngIf="canvasConfig">
  <li><b>Static Configuration</b></li>
  <li><pre>{{canvasConfig | json}}</pre></li>
  <li><b>Changeable Parameters</b></li>
  <li><pre>{{canvasParam | json}}</pre></li>

  <li>
    <label>
      <div>Amount of points</div>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="canvasParam.points" max="10" min="0" step="1">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <div>Margin X</div>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="canvasParam.margin.x" max="1" min="0" step="0.1">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <div>Margin Y</div>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="canvasParam.margin.y" max="1" min="0" step="0.1">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
      <label>
        <div>Stroke Width</div>
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="canvasParam.stroke.width" max="10" min="0" step="0.1">
      </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

App.Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Param } from './models/param.model';
import { Config } from './models/config.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public canvasConfig: Config;
  public canvasParam: Param;
  public test: number;

  constructor() {
    this.canvasParam = {
      colors: {
        start: '#cc0045',
        end: '#0067cc'
      },
      points: 3,
      margin: {
        x: 0.2,
        y: 0.4
      },
      stroke: {
        width: 2
      },
      spread: 80,
      showGrid: true
    };
  }

  changePointCount(e){
    console.log(e.path[0].value);
    this.canvasParam.points = e.path[0].value;
  }

  public updateCanvasConfig(config): void {
    this.canvasConfig = config;
  }
}
```

Comment: start by removing NgModel from imports into the app,module.ts,
Also, please run a "npm intall" and verify that all your package are correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher.  But, the binding is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

NgModle is not a module. it should be :

```
imports: [
  FormsModule
]
```

which you already have. You also don't need FormsModule in your component, since it's already injected to the app component, thus making it available everywhere.

Comment: And this fixes the broken binding?

Comment: Yes. The only thing you need to make ngModel work is 1-FormsModule in your imports, 2- a name attribute on the field, and 3 the binding so:        <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username"> I don't know if you need it, but I would also add CommonModule, as that is essentialy to most things you're going to need

Comment: Sorry, David, I'm just seeing your last response.

Comment: David, does the name attribute have to match the key to be updated?

Comment: no it doesn't have to match. It just has to have one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, in your Imports statement in `App.module.ts` change the below line

```
import { FormsModule, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
```

to

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```